# retrieve the default site URL(azurewebsites.net) from an Azure website (xyz.com)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Azure websites have a default "site URL" , something like mysite.azurewebsites.ne(which i don't have, I only have the xyz.com). Is it possible to get this URL just by knowing the address aka custom domain (xyz.com) , keep in mind that im not the admin of the site and all I have is normal access

Comment: Have you tried doing an `nslookup xzy.com`? If the DNS was set up as a CNAME, and not as an A record, this shoud resolve to xxx.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Hmm thanks for the Tip ill try that tomorrow and report back if it works(the website only works from the company's office)

Comment: it didn't work it returns the server name , looks like the website is using A record because the address dosent have www. it had company.exaple.gov.us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

My answer is valid for the webapp in the public network environment. For the internal URL you provided, I checked and found that it uses `Azure-Application-Gateway`. Therefore, no matter how we query, no matter what tool we use, **we cannot query the information of azure webapp, only the gateway information can be queried**.

[image]

**If you must inquire, you can only contact your administrator who has an azure portal account. Or have azure account information, verify and get help from Microsoft.**

**PRIVIOUS**

I add custom domain. https://aa.backoffice.jasonp2.net

And it also works for me. So I think the way

[image]

[image]

So I think my query method is normal. When I created the custom domain name, I chose the `A` record, and the `CNAME` is displayed on the webpage. I don't know the reason for this.

So I think you can try it. Do the same for your other existing websites. After ensuring that the website is accessible, use my method to see if it can be accessed. Because I think the problem is in your current domain name `bac**ffice.*****.***.ma`. There are some problems with the current resolution, which makes us unable to reverse search.

You can `dns look` to find your original website name. You can visit this web site. https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx

My custom domain name is `www.jasonp2.net`.

[image]

Select `DNS Lookup`, and click, you will find your orginal website url.

[image]

Comment: It dosent seem to work the website dosent start with www (it's using À record not cname like yours)

Comment: @user31731 Can you provide your website URL? I can find other solutions to try. If it involves privacy and needs to be kept confidential, then there is no need.

Comment: Tks，I will tell you in time if there is progress.

Comment: @user31731 Can you provide any url that can get the resource file?

Comment: The site only works from the company office I can send the ressource file to you if you kindly tell me where I could find it, im currently at the office so I have access. I presume youre taking about the Resx file, I dont have admin access to the azure portal

Comment: Thank you for your time, can you please edit out the Web site link  from your answer( for privacy reasons).gov link

Comment: Ok, I deleted it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221183/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-user31731).